# Problem in booting from new installation of Ubuntu 14.04 to a new ssd Hard disk

Tags: grub2, grubrescue, grub-efi

I try a lot of times to install Ubuntu 14.04 toy a new disk in my desktop. But grub never worked. After reboot always goes to rescue grub command line with the message can “open” the disk see image 1.

[image]

My system has the following hard disk structure.

[image]

The last try it was to install the last Ubuntu 15.04 and when it was ready to install the system after the disk forma it show me e message about UEFI something like I push to use UEFI or something like that (I don’t remember what said the message) but after reboot the same problem. I forget to say that when (previews installations)I install in hte Hard dik the ubuntu I din'd had any problem with installetion or grub.
EDIT:
My motherboard is Gigabyte GA-H87-HD3
The result of sudo blkid

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="F84AA0AF4AA06C56" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="13e39544-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="2EB6A8A9B6A872CF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="13e39544-02"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="adac9a65-e121-4000-a2e4-9000372dfee3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="be40ea1a-8031-4024-b8f9-782801d8e085"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="9CA29CF6A29CD65C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="3a0ff180-01"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="5CA815C4A8159E18" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="57980e32-01"
/dev/sdi1: LABEL="UUI" UUID="C2F4-1EFA" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="185c13af-c626-4db3-a276-410f64711637" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="06bd4ae4-38b1-4cbc-bc88-8a66c87ab77d"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try booting your installation medium in "try before installing" mode, open a Terminal window, and type:

```
sudo blkid
```

This command will produce information on your disk partitions, something like this:

```
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SSD_ESP" UUID="E231-242F" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="5028fa50-0079-4c40-b240-abfaf28693ea" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="65e70569-536a-4b50-b7c7-9267359447e8" TYPE="reiserfs"
```

Scan this output for the UUID value (the long hexadecimal number) from the "no such device" error in your first screen shot. If you can find that specific number, then that suggests that for some reason, GRUB can't find your SSD, although Ubuntu can. This can happen when a SATA device is plugged into a port that's not accessible to the firmware, but that is accessible to Linux. In such a case, moving the disk to another SATA port on the motherboard may help. Consult your manual for information about which physical ports are controlled by which disk controller chipsets. If one of your other disks has no bootable OS, you might be able to simply swap cables.

If you don't see the UUID from the message in your `blkid` output, then that suggests that your GRUB configuration is corrupt. This might happen if you're launching an old GRUB from a previous installation. It could also happen if the GRUB setup scripts have a bug. (It looks like your [EFI System Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is on another physical disk than your Ubuntu boot partition, which is unusual enough that it could be triggering a bug that few people encounter.) Two possible solutions/workarounds spring to mind:

- In the Ubuntu live disk, run [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) This tool can fix many GRUB problems, but it's not guaranteed to succeed, particularly if the problem is a GRUB bug.
- Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a medium with it, and boot it. (You may need to disable Secure Boot, if you haven't done so already.) This should give you options to boot Ubuntu and whatever other OS(es) are on your disk. If you can boot all your OSes, boot into Ubuntu and install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package. This should set up rEFInd as your main boot manager, bypassing GRUB.